# Convert Excel to PDF using JavaScript

Tags: pdf, javascript

How can I convert Excel documents (files) to PDF in an automated fashion?
I am trying to adapt the solution found [here](https://superuser.com/a/28303/212009) to Excel. So far I have this:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var docPath = WScript.Arguments(0);
docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath);

var pdfPath = docPath.replace(/\.xls[^.]*$/, ".pdf");
var objExcel = null;

try
{
    WScript.Echo("Saving '" + docPath + "' as '" + pdfPath + "'...");

    objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    objExcel.Visible = false;

    var objExcel = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(docPath);

    var wdFormatPdf = 17;
    objExcel.SaveAs(pdfPath, wdFormatPdf);
    objExcel.Close();

    WScript.Echo("Done.");
}
finally
{
    if (objExcel != null)
    {
        objExcel.Quit();
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
Saving 'somefile.xlsx' as 'somefile.pdf'...
Done.
..\SaveXLSXAsPDF.js(27, 9) (null): The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
```

A PDF file is created but it is invalid and won't open in a reader. I'm thinking that perhaps format 17 isn't the right one for Excel. Does anyone know the right number or how to get this working?

Edit: I found mention of the correct number [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (57) but now I get this error:

```
r:\Web\Roman\SaveXLSXAsPDF.js(27, 13) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Class doesn't support Automation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're clobbering objExcel on line 15:

```
var objExcel = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(docPath);
```

Those lines of code need to use a different variable, e.g.:

```
var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(docPath);

var wdFormatPdf = 57;
objWorkbook.SaveAs(pdfPath, wdFormatPdf);
objWorkbook.Close();
```

Comment: Indeed I was! Search and replace strikes again. That, in combination with discovering 57 was the right format, and it's working now! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `.ExportAsFixedFormat` property instead of `.SaveAs`. First one is suitable for creating PDF files in Excel but not SaveAs which doesn't support PDF format.

I guess you would need something like this:

```
objExcel.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdfPath)
```

Comment: This works too as long as I use objWorkbook as ernie noted. However, saveAs does indeed work with format 57, though I suspect that's because the version of Excel I'm using (2007) has the PDF saving functionality.

Comment: +1 I recommend this as well since various other properties can be set easily at the same time. For example: `(Workbook/Sheet Object).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Example.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True`

Comment: Is there an option to prevent the "Publishing" status bar from popping up after each one when this is done in a loop? I'm procession hundreds of conversions and the pop-up is very intrusive.