# Javascript error "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" when creating ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

So, a colleague of mine is running into a weird error when trying to work with creating an Excel ActiveXObject; as such, I made some test code and put it in a .hta hosted on a network drive:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
JUST FOR AVERY
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
var myBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this code works for me 100% of the time. However, for Avery, she gets the following error:

```
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
```

The line number it gives corresponds with creating the ActiveXObject itself.

We tried setting all Internet Explorer security zones to Low, that way we know that we've covered everything; we then closed all IE/mshta windows, and opened the test code again, and we got the exact same error message.

I'm at a loss here. Help?

**EDIT**

Just to add some key points, just in case:

OS: Windows 7
IE: Internet Explorer 8

Answer (score 0):

After I found [another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673628/convert-excel-to-pdf-using-javascript) about Excel in javaScript, I suppose that the ActiveXObject model is not that reliable/stable as one would expect from javaScript.

Because of that I think may be the way how you used the `Add` function:

```
var myBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add;
```

In javaScript, this means that myBook is "the function `Add`". To get "the result of `Add`" you must use it with brackets:

```
var myBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add();
```

I know VBScript would execute the function with and without the crumbs, but in javaScript, functions are first-class objects. *I could imagine this breaks IE and ActiveXes*.

"First-class objects" means, that every function is also an object:

```
// Save a function object to a variable
var myFunction = function () { };

// and later
// Use the function variable
var result = myFunction();
```

---

Another point may be the "local" parameter of the ActiveXObject constructor, as noted on msdn:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6958xykx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

On Avery's computer IE creates the object implicitly on the remote computer (network share), and that may break your new ActiveXObject.

Try *something like (I can't test that assumptions!)*:

```
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application", 'localhost');
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application", '.');
var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application", '\\\\.\\');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and did the below:

`<html>
`<head>`
`<title>`
`JUST FOR AVERY`
`</title>`
`</head>`
`<body>`
`<script type="text/javascript">`
`var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application", "127.0.0.1");`
`var myBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add();`
`</script>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

And we still get the exact same error message.

EDIT: Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: @J.D.Lowe Sorry it's a really weird error, also when looking for on google. Last try: Map the network share to a volume identifier like `Z:` using credentials for read (and execute), then open the hta using `file:///Z:/your.hta`