# save Excel as pdf using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, pdf

Is there a way to save my excel workbook as PDF in Javascript ?

If no , is it done in Php side (Symfony).

I am working on a REST API project. The front-end is `angular` and the back-end `Symfony`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Excel to PDF using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673628/convert-excel-to-pdf-using-javascript)

Comment: Are you open to commercial (paid) solutions? Also, why is converting excel to PDF in the browser client side important for you? Why not just do it server side?

Comment: Also, this does not appear to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673628/convert-excel-to-pdf-using-javascript since that one is using ActiveX plugin. This question appears to be asking to do conversion completely client side in the browser using javascript.

Comment: i can only use free solutions , since there's no solutions for client side, i'm working on doing it in server now , thanks